# GWAS: marker map based on old genome assembly - can I use the new assembly to look for SNP positions?

Tags: snp, gwas

I have an old set of pig SNP data and the positions were mapped using v10.2 of the assembly.

I submitted a GWAS paper for review, and the reviewer wants to know if any of the significant SNPs that were located in previously unknown genes are now in known genes, with the release of the latest assembly last year.

I was under the impression that I had to use the assembly the marker map was based on to see where SNPs are located. Is this correct or can I use the new assembly?

Many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Why haven't you tried using LiftOver to convert the coordinates?

https://genome.ucsc.edu/cgi-bin/hgLiftOver

Comment: I didn't even know this was possible! Thank you!

Comment: Hello! This question was deemed worth of an answer, so why not upvote it? [Vote early, vote often](https://biology.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22/vote-early-vote-often?rq=1) to encourage new users and keep the community alive!